# How to compare and display the data continuously from the text file?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

At first I am getting the month of event from the text file and from the SAP calendar. And then I am comparing the both month, if both are same then event of the same month should be displayed if I click the navigate button.

It's only displaying the events of the month which is last in the list of text file. I want to display all the events as month wise.

Here is my code:

```
     calendar.attachChangeCurrentDate(function(oEvent) {
     text= text.replace(/-/g,":");
      var amber=text.split(':');

      for (var j=1;j<amber.length;j+=4)
        {

        switch(amber[j]){
        case '01' : amber[j]="Jan"; 
        break;
        case '02' : amber[j]="Feb"; 
        break;
        case '03' : amber[j]="Mar"; 
            break;
        case '04' : amber[j]="Apr"; 
            break;
        case '05' : amber[j]="May"; 
            break;
        case '06' : amber[j]="Jun"; 
            break;
        case '07' : amber[j]="Jul"; 
            break;
        case '08' : amber[j]="Aug"; 
            break;
        case '09' : amber[j]="Sep"; 
            break;
        case '10' : amber[j]="Oct"; 
            break;
        case '11' : amber[j]="Nov"; 
            break;
        case '12' : amber[j]="Dec"; 
            break;
        default:"gokka makka";  
            }
        }

        var comp=oEvent.getParameters().currentDate;
        var tmp=comp.split(' ');
        var disp="";
        for(var p=1;p<amber.length; p=p+4)
        {

        if(amber[p]==tmp[1])
        {
            disp+=amber[p-1]+amber[p]+amber[p+1]+":"+amber[p+2];
            msgLabel.setText(disp);     

        }
        else
        {   msgLabel.setText("no Events");}
        }


        });
```